# How to use tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options to set shape invariants?

Tags: tensorflow, while-loop, shapes

When I running the follow code in model.fit mode, I get error:

ValueError: 'context_vec' has shape (None, 512) before the loop, but shape (None, None) after one iteration. Use tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options to set shape invariants.

Code:

```
    mel_outputs, attn_scores, stop_outputs = [], [], []

    for t in range(0, steps, 2):
        prenet_in = m[:, :, t - 1] if t > 0 else go_frame
        mel_frames, scores, hidden_states, cell_states, context_vec, stop_tokens = self.decoder(encoder_seq, encoder_seq_proj, prenet_in,
        hidden_states, cell_states, context_vec, t, x)
        mel_outputs.append(mel_frames)
        attn_scores.append(scores)

        stop_outputs.extend([stop_tokens] * 2)
```

But I can't see any shape change in training for many time. And in eager_mode, these code works fine. So how to rewrite the code to get the correct answer?I really need your help! Waiting for your reply.

Comment: anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same issue a while ago, I would agree that the code works perfectly in eager mode. The problem is that in graph mode TensorFlow traces the whole code and it tries to run the loops for a couple of iterations to actually trace the loop behavior. So this creates a problem when one tries to do an operation on a tensor that changes the resulting shape to something that is not known e.g. [None, None].

Because you can have only one unknown dimension and that would be your batch size and that creates the problem in the TF loop because either the shapes should be consistent along with the loops or you have to specify the shape invariants for all the tensors that are changing shapes.

In your case, it looks like the tensor `context_vec` is changing the shapes. So to resolve that add these pieces of code at the start of the loop or before the `context_vec`:

```
tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
                shape_invariants=[(context_vec, tf.TensorShape([None]))]
            )
```